# Zulip manage.py syntax error accurs on running script

Tags: python, python-3.x, su, zulip

Fresh installation of Zulip on new Server. Installation went well and everything.

I want to use manage.py to do some things, but when I run something like

```
su zulip ./manage.py shell
```

But I get this error message:

```
./manage.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./manage.py: line 2: `from __future__ import (print_function)'
```

Does anyone have a idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like a shell is trying to execute `manage.py`, rather that the Python interpreter.  Does that file still start with the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`)?  You could try explicitly running it as `python3 manage.py shell`.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, that was my idea as well, but the line is there. When i try to execute it explicitly this comes up:

/usr/bin/python3: /usr/bin/python3: cannot execute binary file

Comment: It's this file: https://github.com/zulip/zulip/blob/master/manage.py

Answer (score 0):

This is an incorrect usage of `su`; it caused `su` to launch `bash ./manage.py shell`, which tried to interpret `manage.py` as a Bash script.  You meant one of these:

```sh
su zulip -c './manage.py shell'
```

```sh
sudo -u zulip ./manage.py shell
```